# Initiate data transfers from Server => Client?

Tags: node.js, express

i want to build a server app in node/express which receives requests from one client and sends information to another client, maybe somehow similar to this:

```html
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var IP_client1 = "10.1.2.3";
var IP_client2 = "10.1.2.4";

//get information from client1
app.get('/client1',function(req,res){
  res.send('OK, will send it to client2");
//==>  How to send to client2 from here?
});

//get information from client2
app.get('/client2',function(req,res){
  res.send('OK, will send it to client1");
//==>  How to send to client1 from here?  
});

//==> How to send data to client1 or/and client2 from here?

app.listen(3000);
```

I know how to handle requests from clients to the server, but how could i simply set up a transfer of data from the server to another arbitrary client?
I went through a lot of tutorials, but no one covers this!

Comment: Have you looked at a [websockets tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-nodejs-and-websockets-to-build-a-chat-service--net-34482)...?

Comment: Thanks for the link! Seems to be what i am looking for (i hope i understand it!)

Comment: socket.io is the thing! I tried to follow the "Get started: Chat application" tutorial on socket.io but got stuck! I can't get the response as exptected! Who knows about it?

Comment: If you have more specific `socket.io` questions, you should create new questions for them. I haven't used it extensively, so not super familiar with the library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, websockets (sockets.io) is what allows free communication through communication channels (sockets).
The tutorial here 
 https://socket.io/get-started/chat/
showed me what to do, but unfortunately there seems to be a little bug (or missing detail) in the clients html file!? 
It needs:
var socket = io.connect('http://local.host:port');
to make it running! Very annoying!
Anyway, i have a better feeling now, and i can step forward to the next problem!